# How to receive the scroll events of MatDialog in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a fixed side nav with links that get highlighted when a particular div in the body is scrolled into view. This functionality works fine, but I need to get this working in an material modal window(MatDialog) that scrolls along with the content. I am not able to access the scroll event of the Modal window within the 'DialogOverviewExampleDialog' component.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: If you got the solution, please share here

Answer (score 0):

#### Instructions

Make sure that overflow on the parent is set to auto and the child element should have overflow: scroll and add the **cdkScrollable** directive to the **parent**

**Hint**: Of course you can also modify the overflow behaviour of the mat-dialog container in order to achieve the result you need. Its just important that you can see a scrollable content in the part you want to listen to.

##### component.html:

```
<div class="main-wrapper" cdkScrollable>
  <div class="sub-content"></div>
</div>
```

##### component.css:

```
.main-wrapper {
   overflow: auto;
}

.sub-content {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

#### module.ts:

```
 imports: [ScrollingModule]
```

#### component.ts:

```
constructor(public scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher) {
      this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe((event: CdkScrollable) => {
          console.log(event)
          //do more stuff with the event
       });
    }
```

#### Full documentation [HERE!](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview)